# Classic ASP Add Events to Outlook

Tags: asp-classic, outlook

Hey Im looking to add a button next to my Events where they can add the event to outlook as a reminder from google I have found this can be done by .ics files ?

Has anyone any experience with this and some sample code perhaps on how this works ?

Thanks

Comment: There are some posts under `ICS [outlook]` on Stackoverflow that may be of interest, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400691/ics-in-outlook-being-sent-as-a-msg-file

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for an on-line university website I was working for. I started with the "Creating Clickable Appointments" article (http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20508) and also used information from "Adding Events to Users Calendars – Part 1 – iCal/vCal" (http://richmarr.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/adding-events-to-users-calendars/). From these, I was able to create 3 icons a user could click on to add an event to their calendar, one for Outlook, one for Google, and one for Yahoo.